# Check date with todays date

Tags: java, android, date

I have written some code to check two dates, a start date and an end date. If the end date is before the start date, it will give a prompt that says the end date is before start date.

I also want to add a check for if the start date is before today (today as in the day of which the user uses the application) How would I do this? ( Date checker code below, also all this is written for android if that has any bearing)

```
if (startYear > endYear) {
    fill = fill + 1;
    message = message + "End Date is Before Start Date" + "\n";
} else if (startMonth > endMonth && startYear >= endYear) {
    fill = fill + 1;
    message = message + "End Date is Before Start Date" + "\n";
} else if (startDay > endDay && startMonth >= endMonth && startYear >= endYear) {
    fill = fill + 1;
    message = message + "End Date is Before Start Date" + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Does this help?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// set the calendar to start of today
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// and get that as a Date
Date today = c.getTime();

// or as a timestamp in milliseconds
long todayInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

// user-specified date which you are testing
// let's say the components come from a form or something
int year = 2011;
int month = 5;
int dayOfMonth = 20;

// reuse the calendar to set user specified date
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

// and get that as a Date
Date dateSpecified = c.getTime();

// test your condition
if (dateSpecified.before(today)) {
  System.err.println("Date specified [" + dateSpecified + "] is before today [" + today + "]");
} else {
  System.err.println("Date specified [" + dateSpecified + "] is NOT before today [" + today + "]");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't millis be also reset to zero at the beginning?

Comment: Use Joda Time's DateMidnight and you don't need to reset anything.

Comment: Milliseconds alse need reset
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
f you do not, there will be problems if you compare the dates the same day.

Comment: Using `Calendar. HOUR` is wrong, since it doesn't reset the AM/PM property, thus if the current time is 13 PM the resulting hour would be 12 PM. Use `Calendar. HOUR_OF_DAY` instead.

Comment: @mark91 Fair comment and answer updated. You can always improve answers by editing yourself.

Comment: @sudocode you're right, I have to get used to it, thanks for your advice

Comment: **Update:** These terrible date-time classes are now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 154):

Don't complicate it that much. Use this easy way. Import DateUtils java class and call the following methods which returns a boolean.

```
DateUtils.isSameDay(date1,date2);
DateUtils.isSameDay(calender1,calender2);
DateUtils.isToday(date1);
```

For more info refer this article [DateUtils Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Checksifacalendardateistoday.htm)

Comment: This is easy, do this.

Comment: Well, this may be easy, but it is important for people to understand that this is example code, seemingly without tests/coverage. It's presented here as some library you can pull in, but it's not different from other code snippets in other answers. It'd be better to pull in a library, such as Joda or Commons, as others mentioned, since you can rely their community maintenance. Sorry for picking at your answer, others may suffer the same problem. **Please, please, use libraries where you can**. If you have to copy code from the web, make sure to test and comprehend before going into production.

Comment: I am getting error: `The method isToday() is undefined for the type DateUtils`.

Comment: @learner this method is only in Android version of DateUtils. For "desktop" JDK use `DateUtils.isSameDay(someday, new Date());`

Comment: I believe this is from apache commons lang

Answer (score 13):

Using pure Java:

```
public static boolean isToday(Date date){
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar specifiedDate  = Calendar.getInstance();
        specifiedDate.setTime(date);

        return today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == specifiedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                &&  today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == specifiedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                &&  today.get(Calendar.YEAR) == specifiedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate
.parse( "2021-01-23" )
.isBefore(
    LocalDate.now(
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
    )
)
```

… or:

```java
try 
{
    org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange range =         
        LocalDateRange.of( 
            LocalDate.of( "2021-01-23" ) ,
            LocalDate.of( "2021-02-21" )
        )
    ;
    if( range.isAfter( 
        LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    ) { … }
    else { … handle today being within or after the range. }
} catch ( java.time.DateTimeException e ) {
    // Handle error where end is before start.
}
```

## Details

The other answers ignore the crucial issue of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

The other answers use outmoded classes.

## Avoid old date-time classes

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid java.util.Date/.Calendar and related classes.

## java.time

- In Java 8 and later use the built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).
- In Java 7 or 6, add the [backport of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project.
- In [Android](http://www.android.com/), use the [wrapped version of that backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalDate`

For date-only values, without time-of-day and without time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 1 );
LocalDate stop = start.plusWeeks( 1 );
```

#### Time Zone

Be aware that while `LocalDate` does not *store* a time zone, *determining* a date such as “today” requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date may vary around the world by time zone. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal. A moment after midnight in Paris is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

If all you have is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use [`ZoneOffset`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZoneOffset.html). If you have a full time zone (continent/region), then use [`ZoneId`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZoneId.html). If you want UTC, use the handy constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

Comparing is easy with `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods.

```
boolean invalidInterval = stop.isBefore( start );
```

We can check to see if today is contained within this date range. In my logic shown here I use the *Half-Open* approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is common in date-time work. So, for example, a week runs from a Monday going up to but not including the following Monday.

```
// Is today equal or after start (not before) AND today is before stop.
boolean intervalContainsToday = ( ! today.isBefore( start ) ) && today.isBefore( stop ) ) ;
```

### `LocalDateRange`

If working extensively with such spans of time, consider adding the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This library extends the java.time framework, and is the proving ground for possible additions to java.time.

ThreeTen-Extra includes an [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html)  class with handy methods such as `abuts`, `contains`, `encloses`, `overlaps`, and so on.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Too wordy. Answer buried in middle. Prefer answer at top and expound if you want.

Comment: @Sun I added a “tl;dr” section up top. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Android already has a dedicated class for this. Check [DateUtils.isToday(long when)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

Comment: Perfect and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) this can be simplified to:

```
DateMidnight startDate = new DateMidnight(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
if (startDate.isBeforeNow())
{
    // startDate is before now
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: This is now Deprecated!

Comment: Also be very careful in the Month Argument - Joda's is in range 1-12 and Java has range 0-11. Can throw an IllegalArgument exception if the month is January and passed from Java. Although it's not documented, it will throw org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException (a subclass of IllegalArgumentException) if the value is invalid.

Comment: Good hint, but IMO Joda's range is the correct one anyway. 0-11 never made sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

to check if a date is today's date or not only check for dates not time included with that so make time 00:00:00 and use the code below

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set the calendar to start of today
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Date today = c.getTime();

    // or as a timestamp in milliseconds
    long todayInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();


    int dayOfMonth = 24;
    int month = 4;
    int year =2013;

    // reuse the calendar to set user specified date
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    // and get that as a Date
    Date dateSpecified = c.getTime();

    // test your condition
    if (dateSpecified.before(today)) {

        Log.v(" date is previou")
    } else if (dateSpecified.equal(today)) {

        Log.v(" date is today ")
    } 
             else if (dateSpecified.after(today)) {

        Log.v(" date is future date ")
    }
```

Hope it will help....

Answer (score 2):

```
    boolean isBeforeToday(Date d) {
        Date today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        return d.before(today);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using integers to represent your year, month, and day? If you want to remain consistent, use the Date methods.

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
int currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay; 
currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

     if(startYear < currentYear)
                {
                    message = message + "Start Date is Before Today" + "\n";
                }
            else if(startMonth < currentMonth && startYear <= currentYear)
                    {
                        message = message + "Start Date is Before Today" + "\n";
                    }
            else if(startDay < currentDay && startMonth <= currentMonth && startYear <= currentYear)
                        {
                            message = message + "Start Date is Before Today" + "\n";
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this operation:

```
public class TimeUtils {

    /**
     * @param timestamp
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isToday(long timestamp) {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar timeToCheck = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeToCheck.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        return (now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == timeToCheck.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                && now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == timeToCheck.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isToday(Date date)
{
    return org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.isSameDay(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),date);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean itIsToday(long date){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        Calendar calendarData = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarData.setTimeInMillis(date);
        calendarData.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendarData.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendarData.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendarData.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarToday.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendarToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendarToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendarToday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendarToday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if(calendarToday.getTimeInMillis() == calendarData.getTimeInMillis()) {
            result = true;
        }
    }catch (Exception exception){
        Log.e(TAG, exception);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: These classes became legacy years ago, with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice. Use only *java.time* classes instead.