# Java - check if date format is acceptable and compare dates based on it

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to create a simple function that gets 2 params - date format(dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy etc...) and a string that in this format(1/4/2015, 1-4-2015).
First of all is there a way to check if the format is acceptable by `SimpleDateFormat` and the next step if the `dateInString` is today, here is my code:

```
public boolean checkDate(String dateInString, String format){
    boolean result = false;      
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    //parse the string to date 
    Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
    //check if the date is today using the format
    //if the date is today then 
    result = true;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (especially the part about the constructor that takes a format)?

Comment: Yes, is there a part for acceaptable dates?

Comment: No you didn't or else you'd seen the "IllegalArgumentException - if the given pattern is invalid" part

Comment: missed that line. still it is only a part of mu question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check date with todays date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537535/check-date-with-todays-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this [Utility class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Checksifacalendardateistoday.htm) (DateUtils) with this implementation:

```
public boolean checkDate(String dateInString, String format){
    try {
        return DateUtils.isToday(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(dateInString)); 
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could `return DateUtils.isToday(date)` inside the `try`, and then drop the  `return false` at the end. Simpler! (You could even inline the `date` variable)

Answer (score 0):

1. For checking the format you could do something like this:

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

   try {
       dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
   }
   catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
       //handle wrong format
   }
   ```
2. Check if date is today

   ```
   dateInString.equals(dateFormat.format(new Date()))
   ```
3. Have a look at Joda Time Library which is much more convenient ;)

PS: Have not tested the, but thats roughly the way to go.

A cleaner way would be to split the method up e.g.

- boolean isDateFormatValid(String format)
- boolean isDateToday(String dateInString, String format)