# How to disable the today date based on time

Tags: android, datepicker

I am doing one application in that i want to disable today date if time is after **10AM**. I am giving one condition, in that i am getting the next date if time is after **10Am** but in calendar today date not disabling. It showing today date, if i am selcting that date then its setting tomorrow date in my edit Text. How to disable the date if time is after 10Am.This is my code.

```
dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ProductDetails.this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    // Display Selected date in textbox
                                    datestr = dayOfMonth + "-"
                                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                                /*datestr = year + "-"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;*/
                                    System.out.println("Datestr is--" + datestr);

                                    date_edit_txt.setText(datestr);

                                    if(value>10){
                                        mDay=mDay+1;
                                        view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);
                                        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mDay);

                                        Log.e("time is >10..","after 10..");

                                    }


                                }

                            }, mDay, mMonth, mYear);



                    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dialog.show();
                }
```

Comment: This is the pure wrong code for your requirement !

Comment: oh? Then how can i acheive my requirement. Now i have only one issue, that is setting the date as next day if time is afetr 10Am

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537535/check-date-with-todays-date)

Comment: if(value>10){
                                            mDay=mDay+1;
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                                           c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
                                            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                                            view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);
                                            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mDay);
  }                                                                                                     previously i agve like this, but its not working